# Is there a way to create Tex Live or LaTeX virtual environment?

Tags: packages, paths, texlive-2018

I am looking for a Python-style virtualenv or venv to create a virtual environment where I can install LaTeX packages such that the packages are available to my current LaTeX project only (but not available system-wide).

I am expecting something like the following:

- Create a virtual-environment path, say, `./venv`.
- Set some environment variables or modify `tlmgr install` commands such that new packages are installed into `./venv` with the proper directory structure.
- Set some environment variables or modify `pdflatex` commands such that the new documents I compile use packages from the `./venv` directory along with the packages in the system-wide paths that came with Tex Live distribution.
- I do not however want to hardcode any `./venv` paths in the LaTeX documents (the `.tex` files). The source code in the `.tex` file should be agnostic of whether it is being compiled with a virtual environment or not.

Comment: @HenriMenke I believe we can create multiple user-trees like this: `tlmgr init-usertree --usertree ~/tex1; tlmgr init-usertree --usertree ~/tex2`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use TeX Live's [user mode](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#USER-MODE) for that purpose.  As you have already mentioned in the comments, you can create a new user tree (allowing multiple trees) using

```
$ tlmgr init-usertree --usertree ~/test-tree
```

To install a package in this tree you have to pass the user tree and the option `--usermode`

```
$ tlmgr install --usertree ~/test-tree --usermode <package>
```

To run LaTeX you have to give it a hint where to look for user packages, by setting the `TEXMFHOME` variable.  You can either do this separately for each run

```
$ TEXMFHOME=~/test-tree pdflatex test.tex
```

or globally for the current shell by exporting the name (use `unset` to exit the “virtual environment”)

```
$ export TEXMFHOME=~/test-tree
$ pdflatex test.tex
$ unset TEXMFHOME
```

Comment: A nice thing about the `TEXMFHOME` variable is that it works with `tlmgr` too. So we can do something like this too: `export TEXMFHOME=~/tree; tlmgr init-usertree; tlmgr --usermode install csquotes; pdflatex foo.tex; unset TEXMFHOME`