# Local bounding box doesn't work inside a scope

Tags: tikz-pgf, scoping

This code:

```
\pic[rotate=40, local bounding box=microfono] at (4.5,-5) {microph};
\draw[black, line width=2pt] (microfono.-45) -- ++(-.2,+.2) ++(.2,-.2) -- ++(0,-2);
```

works outside the `scope` but not inside (the line is not displayed). Why?

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    pics/microph/.style={code={ 
        \draw[black, line width=.2em, rounded corners=1.7ex] 
            (-.85em,4.5ex) -- (-.85em,2ex) -- (.85em,2ex) -- (.85em,4.5ex);
        \fill[black] 
            (-.6em,5ex) to[rounded corners=1.2ex]  
            (-.6em,2.5ex) to[rounded corners=1.2ex] (.6em,2.5ex)
            -- (.6em,5ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)  
            -- (.6em,5.5ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            -- (.6em,6ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            -- (.6em,6.5ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            to[rounded corners=1.2ex]
            (.6em,8ex) to[rounded corners=1.2ex]
            (-.6em,8ex) to cycle; 
    }},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip (-8.5,-6.5) rectangle (8.5,6.5);
\node[fill=cyan, draw=cyan, minimum width=17cm, minimum height=13cm](sky){};
\pic[rotate=40, local bounding box=microfono] at (4.5,-5) {microph};
\draw[black, line width=2pt] (microfono.-45) -- ++(-.2,+.2) ++(.2,-.2) -- ++(0,-2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: delete this line `\clip (-8.5,-6.5) rectangle (8.5,6.5);`

Comment: @AndréC I did a scope just to clip, I cannot delete that line, it is what I need

Comment: Why do you need this line?

Comment: @AndréC To clip the picture, the actual picture is more complex than the MWE.

Comment: There must be an error in the definition of your `{microph} pic`, because with the `{seagull} pic` on page 259 of the manual, you cannot reproduce this problem.

Comment: I'll be critized for this, but you can nest the picture of the microphone inside a node.

Comment: `\node[rotate=40] (microfono) at (4.5,-5) {\begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture}};`

Comment: this work `\pic[rotate=40] (microfono) at (4.5,-5) {seagull};` but not this `\pic[rotate=40] (microfono) at (4.5,-5) {microph};`

Comment: @AndréC Yes, but that does not solve my problem

Comment: I think I get the desired result with: `\path (4.5,-5) pic[rotate=40, pic type=microph]  node(microfono){};`, but I don't understant why the original code don't work.

Comment: @vipa Yes, that works, if you would like to add an answer I'll accept it if no other explanations appear

Comment: @CarLaTeX This does not solve the problem, but it shows that the problem may not be where you are looking for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had originally fixed this use of `local bounding box` in PGF 3.1.5 by executing the `\pgf@path@size@hook` in `\pgf@protocolsizes` unconditionally.  However, this broke all other uses of `local bounding box`.  Unfortunately, I could not think of another solution to make this admittedly very niche situation work.  Nevertheless, I can propose a workaround for using `local bounding box` in a `\clip` context.  Simply add `overlay=false` to the path or scope that you want to get the local bounding box of.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    pics/microph/.style={code={ 
        \draw[black, line width=.2em, rounded corners=1.7ex] 
            (-.85em,4.5ex) -- (-.85em,2ex) -- (.85em,2ex) -- (.85em,4.5ex);
        \fill[black] 
            (-.6em,5ex) to[rounded corners=1.2ex]  
            (-.6em,2.5ex) to[rounded corners=1.2ex] (.6em,2.5ex)
            -- (.6em,5ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)  
            -- (.6em,5.5ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            -- (.6em,6ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            -- (.6em,6.5ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            to[rounded corners=1.2ex]
            (.6em,8ex) to[rounded corners=1.2ex]
            (-.6em,8ex) to cycle; 
    }},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip (-8.5,-6.5) rectangle (8.5,6.5);
\node[fill=cyan, draw=cyan, minimum width=17cm, minimum height=13cm](sky){};
\pic[rotate=40, overlay=false, local bounding box=microfono] at (4.5,-5) {microph};
\draw[black, line width=2pt] (microfono.-45) -- ++(-.2,+.2) ++(.2,-.2) -- ++(0,-2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

the description of `\clip`  contains the sentence "the size of subsequent paths will not be important for the picture size." So I assume that `local bounding box` can't get the correct size.

A simple work around is to draw the micro twice:

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    pics/microph/.style={code={
        \draw[black, line width=.2em, rounded corners=1.7ex]
            (-.85em,4.5ex) -- (-.85em,2ex) -- (.85em,2ex) -- (.85em,4.5ex);
        \fill[black]
            (-.6em,5ex) to[rounded corners=1.2ex]
            (-.6em,2.5ex) to[rounded corners=1.2ex] (.6em,2.5ex)
            -- (.6em,5ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            -- (.6em,5.5ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            -- (.6em,6ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            -- (.6em,6.5ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            to[rounded corners=1.2ex]
            (.6em,8ex) to[rounded corners=1.2ex]
            (-.6em,8ex) to cycle;
    }},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{scope}
\pic[rotate=40, local bounding box=microfono] at (4.5,-5) {microph};
\clip (-8.5,-6.5) rectangle (8.5,6.5);
\node[fill=cyan, draw=cyan, minimum width=17cm, minimum height=13cm](sky){};
\pic[rotate=40] at (4.5,-5) {microph};
\draw[line width=2pt] (microfono.-45) -- ++(-.2,+.2) ++(.2,-.2) -- ++(0,-2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are correct.  The problem here is `local bounding box` which hooks into `\pgf@protocolsizes` but only `\ifpgf@relevantforpicturesize` which seems wrong to me.  The hook should be executed unconditionally.

Comment: The microphone wire marks a break at the point where it is bent.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need a local bounding box here. You can just use some coordinate in the microphone. However, it is known that `pic`s screw up the name prefixes. This bug has been only fixed partially, and according to Henri Menke it will be fixed completely in the next version of pgf. For the time being, let us use [@cfr's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194370) to reset the name prefixing with `name prefix ..`. This solution is what the pgf manual v3.1.4 recommends on p. 263

[image]

Then you can use the tricks from the pgfmanual to give a name to the pic, and to refer to one of its coordinates from outside. This has the additional benefit that you do not have to guess an angle like -45, which will change if you rotate the microphone.

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    pics/microph/.style={code={ 
        \draw[black, line width=.2em, rounded corners=1.7ex] 
            (-.85em,4.5ex) -- (-.85em,2ex) -- (.85em,2ex) -- (.85em,4.5ex);
        \path (0,2ex) coordinate (-plug);   
        \fill[black,name prefix ..] % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/194370 
            (-.6em,5ex) to[rounded corners=1.2ex]  
            (-.6em,2.5ex) to[rounded corners=1.2ex] (.6em,2.5ex)
            -- (.6em,5ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)  
            -- (.6em,5.5ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            -- (.6em,6ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            -- (.6em,6.5ex) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(-.85em,0) to[rounded corners=.2ex] ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            to[rounded corners=1.2ex]
            (.6em,8ex) to[rounded corners=1.2ex]
            (-.6em,8ex) to cycle; 
   }},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip (-8.5,-6.5) rectangle (8.5,6.5);
\node[fill=cyan, draw=cyan, minimum width=17cm, minimum height=13cm](sky){};
\pic[rotate=40] (microfono) at (4.5,-5) {microph};
\draw[black, line width=2pt] (microfono-plug)   -- ++(.2,-.2) -- ++(0,-2);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with `name prefix`.  Your “fix” was just a coincidence because you removed `local bounding box`.

Comment: @HenriMenke I am aware of this, and, as written in the answer, my, or more precisely cfr's, fix made the local bounding box unnecessary.  It allows one to access the coordinates from outside. My understanding is that the local bounding box is only a tool that was introduced because of the fix it is not possible to do so.

Comment: I see.  That `name prefix` thing is fixed on the latest master https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/88951be592b558b94b14a97aaffe9df6c1ce61ee.  I hope I can release 3.1.5 before Christmas.

Comment: @HenriMenke Sounds great! (I wish I was more proficient with GitHub such that I could try out things.)

Comment: That is why I provide the TeX Live repository which always brings you the latest master automatically with your TeX Live update: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf#installation

Comment: @HenriMenke I saw this but it is not clear to me if this will destroy working TeX Live installation, which is why I did not dare to touch it. (I am also using LaTeX for my daily work, and would hate to see it broken.)

Comment: The “nuke the complete TeX Live installation” switch is currently disabled ;-).  The only thing it can break is Ti*k*Z, of course, but I try hard to not do that.  If it does break you should open a bug report.  I think I react relatively fast.

Comment: @HenriMenke OK, but then, if you try to answer questions, you may end up not being able to reproduce a bug because in the developer version it is already fixed. Is that true? I know that several users are able to run code on different TeX installations, something that I never tried to do.

Comment: If your whole purpose of using Ti*k*Z is to find workarounds for bugs that have been fixed already, then yes, you will not be able to reproduce them.

Comment: @HenriMenke My question is more if one can selectively switch on and off the developer version when one compiles.

Comment: Then you should look at https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf#development.  With the first three command you can switch to the development version in your active shell session.  However, that does not update automatically.  You will have to go to the directory where you cloned and perform `git pull origin master` when you want to update.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/448263/is-there-a-way-to-create-tex-live-or-latex-virtual-environment

Comment: @HenriMenke Given your own answer it would be a really great idea if you removed your first comment above. The bottom-line seems to be that there is no complete fix, so there is really no reason to criticize an answer that makes the use of the `local bounding box` unnecessary. IMHO this remains the by far simplest and sustainable solution to the problem.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in my comments the problem arises with your `pic {microph}` and not with the first `pic {seagull}` defined on section `18 Pics: Small Pictures on Paths` of the TikZ manual. This clearly shows that there is a **bug** in the source code of the `pic operation`. This bug makes the `to` operations in the code of a `pic` incompatible.

The problem comes from a bug in the `pic` operation that does not tolerate `to` operations. 
By replacing these operations with `--`, it works.

You do not need a local box because the `pic` allow you to place `node` accessible from the outside with the `prefix name` as shown on section `18.2 The Pic Syntax` of the manual. So I added a coordinate called the `(-milieu)` to the right where the wire connects: in the middle of the bottom of the microphone.

```
\draw[black, line width=.2em, rounded corners=1.7ex,pic actions] 
            (-.85em,4.5ex) -- (-.85em,2ex) -- (.85em,2ex)coordinate[midway](-milieu) -- (.85em,4.5ex);
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    pics/microph/.style={code={ 
        \draw[black, line width=.2em, rounded corners=1.7ex,pic actions] 
            (-.85em,4.5ex) -- (-.85em,2ex) -- (.85em,2ex)coordinate[midway](-milieu) -- (.85em,4.5ex);
        \fill[black,pic actions]  
            (-.6em,5ex)[rounded corners=1.2ex]  --% 
            (-.6em,2.5ex)[rounded corners=1.2ex] --%to 
            (.6em,2.5ex)
            -- (.6em,5ex)[rounded corners=.2ex] --%to 
            ++(-.85em,0)[rounded corners=.2ex]  --%to
            ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)  
            -- (.6em,5.5ex)[rounded corners=.2ex] --%to 
            ++(-.85em,0)[rounded corners=.2ex] --%to 
            ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            -- (.6em,6ex)[rounded corners=.2ex] --%to 
            ++(-.85em,0)[rounded corners=.2ex]  --%to
            ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            -- (.6em,6.5ex)[rounded corners=.2ex] --%to 
            ++(-.85em,0)[rounded corners=.2ex] --%to 
            ++(0,.35ex) -- ++(.85em,0)
            [rounded corners=1.2ex]--%to
            (.6em,8ex) [rounded corners=1.2ex]--%to
            (-.6em,8ex) --%to
             cycle; 
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip (-8.5,-6.5) rectangle (8.5,6.5);
\node[fill=cyan, draw=cyan, minimum width=17cm, minimum height=13cm](sky){};
\pic[rotate=40] (microfono) at (4.5,-5) {microph};
\draw[black, line width=2pt] (microfono-milieu) -- ++(.2,-.2) -- ++(0,-2);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thank you. Do you want to report this bug to Henri Menke so he can fix it?

Comment: I'll try to do it, thanks

Comment: That is a coincidence because you removed `local bounding box`.  The `to` operation works just fine in `pic`.

Comment: @HenriMenke Indead, the manual say on page 259 `Unlike nodes, pics cannot be referenced later on. You can reference nodes that are inside a pic, but not
“the pic itself”. In particular, you cannot draw lines between pics the way you can draw them between nodes. In general, whenever it makes sense that some drawing could conceivably be connected to other node-like-things, then a node is better than a pic.` So, the use of a `local bounding box` is in itself wrong.