# TikZ: \clip inside \pic not working?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Doesn't `\clip` work (= clip all subsequent drawing) if it is defined inside a `pic`?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
   crop/.pic={
        \clip (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    }
}

\newcommand*{\clipshape}{\clip (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\draw[very thick,color=black,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{2*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\clip (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east); % THIS WORKS
\draw[very thick,color=black,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{2*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\clipshape % THIS WORKS
\draw[very thick,color=black,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{2*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\pic{crop}; % THIS DOESN'T WORK
\draw[very thick,color=black,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{2*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: related : https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/518638/138900

Comment: A pic is a little bit like a scope. If you say `\begin{scope} \clip (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east); \end{scope}` the clip won't affect the stuff after `\end{scope}` either. So the bottom-line is that a `clip` in a `pic` only affects stuff inside the pic. (Otherwise it would be fatal for many pics which precisely use local clips.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pic is in this regard like a scope. It only clips what is inside the pic. Recall that for scopes

```
\begin{scope} 
 \clip <some path>;
 <stuff> 
\end{scope}
<more stuff>
```

the clip affects only the `<stuff>` in the scope but not the `<more stuff>` not that follows afterwards. So, yes, you cannot use `crop` as you intend. Your `\newcommand` or some pgf key is fine.

However, `pic`s also allow you to make this unnecessary. You can define a pic, `plot`, say, that does all of that and takes the function as a parameter,

```
\tikzset{pics/plot/.style={code={
    \draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
    \clip(current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \draw[very thick,color=black,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{#1});}}
}
```

Here `\clip` works again, as the MWE shows.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{
   crop/.pic={
        \clip (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    },
    pics/plot/.style={code={
    \draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
    \clip(current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
    \draw[very thick,color=black,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{#1});}}
}

\newcommand*{\clipshape}{\clip (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\draw[very thick,color=black,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{2*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\clip (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east); % THIS WORKS
\draw[very thick,color=black,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{2*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\clipshape % THIS WORKS
\draw[very thick,color=black,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{2*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\pic{crop}; % THIS DOESN'T WORK
\draw[very thick,color=black,domain=-5:5] plot (\x,{2*\x});
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic{plot={2*\x}}; % works
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Please note that you can make the `plot` pic such more flexible if needed by using pgf keys.