# Arrows mess up bounding box of pics

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-pic

I use pics to reuse more sophisticates images multiple times in a drawing. To easily connected them with lines/arrows I name the bounding box of each pic, so they get a bit a node-like behavior.

Now I realize that if I use an arrow in a pic the bounding box is not longer around the pic but also includes the 0/0 - point.

For a better understanding check my MWE (I am quite new to TikZ so any tips are welcomed); The dashed line is the bounding box. As you can see for a pic without arrows (red) and a scope (blue) it works as expected, but for the pic with an arrow (red) the bounding box is wrong.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[mode=buildnew]{standalone}


\begin{document}
\begin{standaloneframe}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
withArrow/.pic = {
    \begin{scope}[shift = {(-2,-2)}, local bounding box = withArrow] % the shift is for easier placing the pic. 
        \draw[thick] (0,2) -- (4,2) (2,0)--(2, 4);
        \draw[thin, ->,] (1,1) -- (3,3);
    \end{scope}
},
withoutArrow/.pic = {
    \begin{scope}[shift = {(-2,-2)}, local bounding box = withoutArrow] 
    \draw[thick] (0,2) -- (4,2) (2,0)--(2, 4);
    \end{scope}
}
]

            
% Mark 0/0 point just for orientation
\node[circle, draw = black] (Zero) {0/0};


% Pic without Arrow works as expected
\pic at(3,3) {withoutArrow};

% Bounding box 
\draw [green, dashed] (withoutArrow.south west) rectangle (withoutArrow.north east);

% Pic with Arrow; bounding box is extended to incluce 0/0 point
\pic at(3,-3) {withArrow};

% Bounding box 
\draw [red, dashed] (withArrow.south west) rectangle (withArrow.north east);




% Scope works also with arrow fine
\begin{scope}[scale = 1, shift = {(6,-2)}, local bounding box = scope]
    \draw[thick] (0,2) -- (4,2) (2,0)--(2, 4);
    \draw[thin, ->,] (1,1) -- (3,3);
\end{scope}

\draw [blue, dashed] (scope.south west) rectangle (scope.north east);







\end{tikzpicture}

\end{standaloneframe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that the shift inside pic cause this problem.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I tried it without the shift and found that it makes no difference.

Comment: I tried a lot, it seems that when there is a shift transformation, the arrow is drawn twice.

Comment: I deleted all the `shift` but still have the issue. But interestingly, if I put the `pic` after the `scope`, the scope has now the box issue. I am really confused... but I can now work around the if I first have a `scope` with an (invisible) arrow.

Comment: Remove your first two examples, left only the last, you will see the problem.

Comment: But this only works since now the 0/0 point lies on the bounding box of the scope, doesn't it? If you change the coordinates of the lines / arrows, so they don't start at 0 the problem is here again. 

But if you then copy the last example, the second instance has a normal bounding box. This actually also works if you copy a `pic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simplified example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \draw[->, xshift=1cm, local bounding box=x] (0, 0) -- (1, 1);
  \draw[blue, dashed] (x.south west) rectangle (x.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In PGF 3.1.5b, the latest released PGF in Jun 2020, `\pgf@path@size@hook` is executed unconditionally in `\pgf@protocolsizes` (in order to fix [this issue](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/795)), and this causes your problem. The maintainer of PGF has *reverted* that change in the latest repository of PGF, see [this commit](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/commit/ca1f30e1fb33789142c306d68cc346b89f771207), and this should fix your problem.

So as a workaround before the next PGF release, you can fix your problem by adding following redefinition of `\pgf@protocolsizes` to the preamble of your tex file:

```
\makeatletter
\def\pgf@protocolsizes#1#2{%
  \ifpgf@relevantforpicturesize%
    \ifdim#1<\pgf@picminx\global\pgf@picminx#1\fi%
    \ifdim#1>\pgf@picmaxx\global\pgf@picmaxx#1\fi%
    \ifdim#2<\pgf@picminy\global\pgf@picminy#2\fi%
    \ifdim#2>\pgf@picmaxy\global\pgf@picmaxy#2\fi%
    \ifpgf@size@hooked%
      \let\pgf@size@hook@x#1\let\pgf@size@hook@y#2\pgf@path@size@hook%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \ifdim#1<\pgf@pathminx\global\pgf@pathminx#1\fi%
  \ifdim#1>\pgf@pathmaxx\global\pgf@pathmaxx#1\fi%
  \ifdim#2<\pgf@pathminy\global\pgf@pathminy#2\fi%
  \ifdim#2>\pgf@pathmaxy\global\pgf@pathmaxy#2\fi%
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 1):

This is ***not the answer***, just some examples to show the problem.

- teal box: local bounding box
- brown box: current bounding box

### Problem

#### First path with arrow seems to extend the local bounding box.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[scale = 1, shift = {(3 ,1)}, local bounding box = scope]
    \draw[thin, ->,] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{scope}
  \node [fit=(current bounding box.south west)(current bounding box.north east), draw=brown] {};
  \draw [teal] (scope.south west) rectangle (scope.north east);
  \draw[thin, ->, gray] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \draw[cyan] (0, 0) -- +(3, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### If a path with arrow is constructed before:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[->] (0, 0) -- (.1, .1);
  \begin{scope}[scale = 1, shift = {(3 ,1)}, local bounding box = scope]
    \draw[thin, ->,] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{scope}
  \node [fit=(current bounding box.south west)(current bounding box.north east), draw=brown] {};
  \draw [teal] (scope.south west) rectangle (scope.north east);
  \draw[thin, ->, gray] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \draw[cyan] (0, 0) -- +(3, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### If a path with arrow is drawn before:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[->] (0, 0) -- (.1, .1);
  \begin{scope}[scale = 1, shift = {(3 ,1)}, local bounding box = scope]
    \draw[thin, ->,] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \end{scope}
  \node [fit=(current bounding box.south west)(current bounding box.north east), draw=brown] {};
  \draw [teal] (scope.south west) rectangle (scope.north east);
  \draw[thin, ->, gray] (0,0) -- (1,1);
  \draw[cyan] (0, 0) -- +(3, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `local bounding box` has been switched back and forth, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/545796) for some backup of the statement. In the next version of pgf it will be again different. In a way the current version was to make some other user happy. So, unfortunately, whatever you find here may no longer be true in version 3.1.5. :-(